# Add a cursor to each selected block in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have the letter p on multiple lines, so when I double click it it selects all the the stand-alone `p`'s.  It doesn't select the `p`'s inside other words, exactly how I want it to be.  Now, what is the shortcut to add the cursor to each of those selected blocks?  I've been surfing the web for a solid 30 minutes trying to find one simple shortcut and it's quite frustrating because I feel like I used to know this too, but no one has it listed.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work because it simply finds the next letter `p`, which happens to be inside many words I don't want to edit.  Also I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> because `p` is only one letter and there is no word for the cursor to be inside of. :( Please help!

Using ubuntu, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the space before and after the `p`, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> (Quick Find All) then you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but what I think is you want to select all the P's in a specific block of text.
If that, just select the text, press Ctrl-F, type p, and click Find all. It will select all the P's in the selection.